# Is it possible to find items by tag?

Tags: windows-phone-7

I have a list of checkboxes each with specific tag, is it possible to identify and get the TextBox item using just the tag? If so, what's the function call for it?

Comment: You want the TextBox? Is that what the tag is? Or are you mixing up checkboxes and textboxes? Unclear exactly what your looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to navigate the visual tree, which defines your UI, to find elements based on their properties. I use [Linq-to-VisualTree](http://www.scottlogic.co.uk/blog/colin/2010/03/linq-to-visual-tree/) (which I wrote) to simplify this task. Let's say you have the following markup:

```
<StackPanel x:Name="stack">
    <CheckBox>
      <TextBox Tag="one"/>
    </ChecBox>
    <CheckBox>
      <TextBox Tag="two"/>
    </ChecBox>
    <CheckBox>
      <TextBox Tag="three"/>
    </ChecBox>
</StackPanel>
```

You can find the second TextBox via the following:

```
TextBox txtBox = stack.Descendants<TextBox>()
                      .Cast<TextBox>()
                      .Where(i => i.Tag="two")
                      .Single();
```

Comment: Have you considered putting this on github and nuget? Zips on blogs frighten me.